# Is there a way to do full disk encryption after the install?

Tags: encryption

Is there a way to do full disk encryption after the install?

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed with /home encrypted but really need the whole drive encrypted.  I would really like to do that with out a re-install.  Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: With Ubuntu 16.04 it is possible - https://askubuntu.com/a/1107295/723997

Answer (score 14):

[LUKS in-place encryption](http://www.johannes-bauer.com/linux/luksipc/) exists. But you need to set up your environment a little as per the pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Also see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70929))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems the Lukispc author recommends cryptsetup-reencrypt but that requires UEFI; https://github.com/johndoe31415/luksipc

Answer (score 6):

No. Part of full disk encryption, Truecrypt or otherwise, is writing random data to the hard drive.

Best you could do (without a re-install) would be to migrate your home to encryption or make a encrypted data partition. You could use Truecrypt or LUKS (I personally use LUKS).

Comment: "writing random data to the hard drive" - this is totally optional and not the root cause for marking this not possible. One could change the initramfs configuration, `crypttab`, `fstab`, make a separate `/boot` partition, copy everything over to a new encrypted volume. It's hard, though. I would re-install everything copy data back as well.

Comment: This answer is not correct. You would indeed want to write-over existing data with encrypted (or random) data, but that doesn't mean it's impossible to encrypt a drive in-place. Plenty of operating systems do it and LUKS supports in-place encryption.