# Ubuntu Live Cd Security

Tags: root, live-cd

I am new to Linux so i have some concerns regarding live cd . If i can log in the system with the live cd and get root access then any on can do the same , so my question is how to stop anyone using live cd to get access to my system , if that is possible .

Comment: The best bet is to encrypt your drive / home folder.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/96870/is-there-a-way-to-do-full-disk-encryption-after-the-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by 'your system' you mean your already installed OS as opposed to the Live CD.

The only way I can think of would be to use full disk encryption with a strong password over the partition(s) that contain your OS. If someone has physical access to your system (ie. can insert a CD or their own hard drives) then this really is the only way to prevent unauthorized access. You can password protect your BIOS so that you need to enter a password to change boot order and boot a CD, but if someone has access they can just flash the CMOS and reset this.

Another alternative to full disk encryption would be to prevent physical access to your system, either with a lock that prevents someone from opening your case, or moving the system to a secure location.

You can read this help page for more help about encryption on ubuntu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto

Comment: thanks for the reply , physically securing the system would be a nice step ,  : )